# How to understand the failure of solving nonlinear equation systems in the Modelica model?

Tags: modelica, dymola

With the following setup in Dymola, the model in Modelica Standard Library (`Modelica.Fluid.Examples.HeatingSystem`) would cause a lot of errors about failing to solve nonlinear equations, even though in the end, nonlinear solver handles this issue successfully, but I don't understand this process.

My question is :
Is there some simple example that demonstrates this process with more details?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the key problem here is that Dymola prints `Error` although it can recover from the problem. That is confusing, and will be improved.

Comment: But sometimes Dymola couldn’t recover from the problem, so I think it is better to avoid these problems, i.e. avoid nonlinearity  as much as possible. But based on the current error message generated by Dymola, it is hard to find the error source.

Comment: In the model I build for solar power plants, I got jammed because of this kind of failure. Here is the screenshot: https://imgur.com/QpQPZtD